# Unable to import from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I have installed imblearn using

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
#version:
conda version : 4.4.10
conda-build version : 3.4.1
python version : 3.6.4.final.0
```

I keep getting error related to numpy and scipy like 
module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'mtrand'
module 'numpy.polynomial' has no attribute 'polynomial'

np.**version**
Out[11]: '1.14.0'

scipy.**version**
Out[17]: '1.2.1'

Please let me know how to fix this

Also, I am unable to import any sklearn package. I tried:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

For these I get Requirement already up-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, instead:

```
pip install imblearn
```

There are two different packages, SMOTE, and SMOTEENN

Comment: I get Requirement already satisfied after running this command from anaconda prompt.

Comment: You want to import SMOTE ?

Comment: yes. also i want to import all these  from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE,
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier,
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split.  for all these i keep getting error related to : 
  File "C:\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 184, in check_random_state
    return np.random.mtrand._rand

AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'mtrand'

Comment: Did you run pip install scipy --upgrade ?

Comment: issue is resolved now. i uninstalled/install anaconda and then used pip install imblearn.

Comment: This works for me too. But first,  I had to downgrade the anaconda version from 4.8 to 3.6 using >conda install -n root conda=4.6